# Inline-block doesn't act as it is supposed to

Tags: html, css, web

I would like to display the content with an inline-block like this : 
[IMAGE1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ero0I.png)
[image]

Actually I'm doing this by adding backlines balises but it's not appropriate...

I was thinking of adding an display: inline-block but the result is worse :
[IMAGE2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lw1uR.png)
[image]
Here is my index.html :

```
<div id="Global">
  <div id="Formation">
    <div id="columnNames">FORMATION</div>
    <div id="content">
      - <a title="Cliquez pour plus d'informations !" href="formation/esisar.html"><I>2015 - 2020</I><br>
      &emsp;<B>É</B>cole <B>S</B>upérieure d’<B>I</B>ngénieurs en <B>S</B>ystèmes <B>A</B>vancés et <B>R</B>éseaux (ESISAR)<br></a>
      - <a title="Cliquez pour plus d'informations !" href="formation/lycee.html"><I>2012 - 2015</I><br>
      &emsp;Lycée Camille Vernet - Valence - Bac S Section Européenne Allemand - Mention Bien</a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <br><br><br><br>
  <hr>


  <div id="Skills">
    <div id="columnNames">COMPETENCES</div>
    <div id="content">
      - <a title="Cliquez pour plus d'informations !" href="competences/latex.html">Maîtrise du langage de documentation scientifique LaTeX<br></a>
      - <a title="Cliquez pour plus d'informations !" href="competences/progimperative.html">Maitrise des langages de programmation impérative (C, C++, Python)<br></a>
      - <a title="Cliquez pour plus d'informations !" href="competences/objet.html">Maitrise des langages de programmation objet (C++, Python, Java)<br></a>
      - <a title="Cliquez pour plus d'informations !" href="competences/sql.html">Maîtrise du langage de requêtage SQL<br></a>
      - <a title="Cliquez pour plus d'informations !" href="competences/web.html">Notions en langages WEB (HTML, CSS et JavaScript)<br></a>
      - <a title="Cliquez pour plus d'informations !" href="competences/linux.html">Système d’exploitation LINUX (Administration et Programmation)<br></a>
      - <a title="Cliquez pour plus d'informations !" href="competences/secnumedu.html">Certification SecNumEdu ANSSI – Formation Initiale en Cybersécurité<br></a>
      - <a title="Cliquez pour plus d'informations !" href="competences/toeic.html">Anglais – TOEIC 940 points (14/12/2018) – Niveau C1<br></a>
      - <a title="Cliquez pour plus d'informations !" href="competences/allemand.html">Allemand – Niveau B1<br></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And my .css linked to this :

```
div#Global{
  padding-bottom: 8px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  line-height: 30px;
}

div#Formation{
  display: inline-block;
}

div#columnNames {
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
    width: 15%;
    color: #7E97AD;
}

div#content {
    float: right;
    text-align: justify;
    width: 83%;
}
```

Comment: That looks like a job for `grid`, not `inline-block`.

Comment: Don't use hyphens and line breaks (`<br>`) for enumerations like this. That is what `<ul>` and `<li>` are for. And using the same title text "Click here for more Information" on all links is pointless.

Comment: And you are misusing IDs. IDs should be used for scripting, not for CSS, especially since duplicate IDs are not allowed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
div#Formation{
  display: inline-block;
  width:100%;
}
```

```css
div#Global{
  padding-bottom: 8px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  line-height: 30px;
}

div#Formation{
  display: inline-block;
  width:100%;
}

div#columnNames {
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
    width: 15%;
    color: #7E97AD;
}

div#content {
    float: right;
    text-align: justify;
    width: 83%;
}
```

```html
<div id="Global">
  <div id="Formation">
    <div id="columnNames">FORMATION</div>
    <div id="content">
      - <a title="Cliquez pour plus d'informations !" href="formation/esisar.html"><I>2015 - 2020</I><br>
      &emsp;<B>É</B>cole <B>S</B>upérieure d’<B>I</B>ngénieurs en <B>S</B>ystèmes <B>A</B>vancés et <B>R</B>éseaux (ESISAR)<br></a>
      - <a title="Cliquez pour plus d'informations !" href="formation/lycee.html"><I>2012 - 2015</I><br>
      &emsp;Lycée Camille Vernet - Valence - Bac S Section Européenne Allemand - Mention Bien</a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <br><br><br><br>
  <hr>


  <div id="Skills">
    <div id="columnNames">COMPETENCES</div>
    <div id="content">
      - <a title="Cliquez pour plus d'informations !" href="competences/latex.html">Maîtrise du langage de documentation scientifique LaTeX<br></a>
      - <a title="Cliquez pour plus d'informations !" href="competences/progimperative.html">Maitrise des langages de programmation impérative (C, C++, Python)<br></a>
      - <a title="Cliquez pour plus d'informations !" href="competences/objet.html">Maitrise des langages de programmation objet (C++, Python, Java)<br></a>
      - <a title="Cliquez pour plus d'informations !" href="competences/sql.html">Maîtrise du langage de requêtage SQL<br></a>
      - <a title="Cliquez pour plus d'informations !" href="competences/web.html">Notions en langages WEB (HTML, CSS et JavaScript)<br></a>
      - <a title="Cliquez pour plus d'informations !" href="competences/linux.html">Système d’exploitation LINUX (Administration et Programmation)<br></a>
      - <a title="Cliquez pour plus d'informations !" href="competences/secnumedu.html">Certification SecNumEdu ANSSI – Formation Initiale en Cybersécurité<br></a>
      - <a title="Cliquez pour plus d'informations !" href="competences/toeic.html">Anglais – TOEIC 940 points (14/12/2018) – Niveau C1<br></a>
      - <a title="Cliquez pour plus d'informations !" href="competences/allemand.html">Allemand – Niveau B1<br></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `width:100%` with `display:inline-block` so it acts as per your requirement,

`display:inline-block` take width as per content not full and `display:block` take full width